# site usage, bulk statistics on new questions/votes/comments/users over time

Tags: feature-request, site-enhancement, site-faq

Is there any condensed info on site usage, bulk statistics on new questions/votes/comments/users over time just like on a user page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is in the moderator tools. It is not made public on a on-going basis.

I'd have to do a little reading to recall what the policy on answering analytics questions is, but if there is something specific you're interested in knowing it would help if you would say what.

---

I should say that you can do a lot of your own analysis with [the data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) and/or the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ah, thx, I'll look into the dumps then